# used python -v instead of python -version command, to find the version of python in my pc. does it change anything?

Tags: python, versions

I wanted to know which version of python is installed on my Xubuntu 16.04. But I typed `python -v` instead of `python -V`.  It then started to import some files. Did this cause harm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `python -v` has not changed anything or done any harm.

Upon initialization, It will show you the modules that are being initialized and the respective files from which they are being loaded. Upon exit, it will show you the unloading information of the loaded modules. So, for understanding, you can take `-v` as verbose.

On the other hand, to get the version, use `python -V` or `python --version`.

Also, in these kind of situations always start with reading the `man` page i.e. do `man python`.

Comment: thanks.... @heemayl  .... i at the end, Ihad tried to copy the message and pasted right there..... got some syntax errors and then I closed the terminal........ but  thanks again for the help

Answer (score 2):

When not sure of commands best to check man in terminal. Most packages have a man command

```
man python
```

> ```
>    -v     Print  a  message each time a module is initialized, showing the
>           place (filename or built-in module) from  which  it  is  loaded.
>           When  given twice, print a message for each file that is checked
>           for when searching for a module.  Also provides  information  on
>           module cleanup at exit.
>
>    -V ,  --version
>           Prints the Python version number of the executable and exits.
> ```

Comment: And most packages have a '--help' parameter, which is shorter than the man pages.

Comment: And most operating systems have a 'man' command. Guess where I had to install it today? ;)